# Print a pyramid of a specific type

Tags: python, string

For uni we have to print a pyramid of a specific type.

Here is the code:

```
h = 10
def build_string_pyramid():
    s = ''

    for i in range(1, h + 1):
        print('1', end='')
        for j in range(2, i + 1):
            print('*', end='')
            print(j, end='')
        print('\r')

    for o in range(h - 1, 0, -1):
        print('1', end='')
        for p in range(2, o + 1):
            print('*', end='')
            print(p, end='')
        print('\r')

    return s
print(build_string_pyramid())
```

The problem is, that we have to submit the resulting Pyramid in the string `s`. I don't know how to import the printed things to the string `s`.

Comment: You shouldn't have printed anything along the way, you should have appended things to the string `s` instead.

Comment: Okay, i get it. But how can i add something to a string? Or in other words, what is the command for this? s+=... or what?

Comment: @eagleadmiral. You may want to read through the tutorial again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace every call of the form `print(...)` with `s += ...`. Keep track of the line endings, so normal `print` appends a `\n`, and `print(..., end='')` is just a simple append. Also, do try to avoid globals:

```
def build_string_pyramid(h=10):
    s = ''

    for i in range(1, h + 1):
        s += '1'               # print('1', end='')
        for j in range(2, i + 1):
            s += f'*{j}'       # print('*', end=''), print(j, end='')
        s += '\n'              # print('\r')

    for o in range(h - 1, 0, -1):
        s += '1'               # print('1', end='')
        for p in range(2, o + 1):
            s += f'*{p}'       # print('*', end=''), print(p, end='')
        s += '\n'              # print('\r')

    return s

print(build_string_pyramid())
```

Appending strings like that is not necessarily optimal, since they get reallocated every time. You may want to build up a list first, or even a list of lists per line, and then `join` them:

```
def build_string_pyramid(h=10):
    s = []

    for i in range(1, h + 1):
        s.append('*'.join(str(j) for j in range(1, i + 1)))

    for o in range(h - 1, 0, -1):
        s.append('*'.join(str(p) for p in range(1, o + 1)))

    return '\n'.join(s)

print(build_string_pyramid())
```

Notice how `str.join` places the delimiters only between the items in a list or generator, so you will get a string with one fewer trailing newline.

As a totally different method, you can go back to your original printing technique, and actually build a string that way too. You can do this by using [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO), which is a file-like object that writes to memory, and allows you to export a string directly:

```
from io import StringIO

def build_string_pyramid(h=10):
    s = StringIO()

    for i in range(1, h + 1):
        print('1', end='', file=s)
        for j in range(2, i + 1):
            print(f'*{j}', end='', file=s)
        print(file=s)

    for o in range(h - 1, 0, -1):
        print('1', end='', file=s)
        for p in range(2, o + 1):
            print(f'*{p}', end='', file=s)
        print(file=s)

    return s.getvalue()

print(build_string_pyramid())
```

Comment: Thank you! Very nice of you. Im still learning but eventually i will make it!